# Well definedness of Lebesgue inner measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

This is for homework: if $A,A'$ are two elementary sets containing $E$, bounded set in $\mathbf{R}^d$, then $m(A)-m^*(A \backslash E)$ is equal to $m(A')-m^*(A \backslash E)$

So far my goal has been to show that they're both equal to the expression for $A \cap A'$ which is another elementary set.

I've done this work: $m(A)-m^*(A\backslash E) = m(A \cap A') + m(A \backslash A') - m^*((A \backslash A') \cup (A \cap A') \backslash E)$

Countable additivity of disjoint sets would be very nice here, but I can't think of why countable additivity would apply in this case (one set is elementary, the other not). So I don't know if I'm on the right track or not. I could try a regularity argument but I can't wrap my head around the strategy there.

Comment: For people who come here by Google, this is Exercise 1.2.18 in Terence Tao's measure theory book.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carath%C3%A9odory%27s_criterion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One idea is to show that the inner measure is in fact

$$\sup \left\{ \lambda(K) : K \subseteq E, \text{ Measurable } \right\} $$

I think an elementary set $A$ is bounded by definiton (perhaps we should check this, if not you may be able to work around, either way here is the case for if $A$ is bounded.)

$$ \lambda(A) - \lambda^{\star}(A\setminus E) = \lambda(A) - \inf\left\{ \lambda(B) : A\supseteq B \supset(A \setminus E), \text{ Measurable } \right\}$$

Now $B$ is measurable, so $\lambda(B) + \lambda( A \setminus B) = \lambda(A)$ hence since $A$ is bounded, we can rewrite $\lambda(B) = \lambda(A) - \lambda(A\setminus B)$, hence we have

$$\lambda(A) - \lambda^{\star}(A\setminus E) = \lambda(A) - \inf\left\{ \lambda(A) - \lambda(C) : C\subseteq  E \right\}$$

But this is nothing else but what we want.

So we see the definition does not depend on $A$.